# how to change placeholder textSize in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my `TextInput` I want to change the size of the font of `placeHolder`, I tried like this:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.email}
    value={this.state.email} 
    placeholder="Email"
    placeholderTextColor="red"
    //placeholderTextSize = 20px
    onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}
    onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}/>
```

when I wrote like this color is working for me but size is not working, can any one give me suggestions how to change the size of placeholder Text, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure if you can specify only the size of placeholderText. But you can change the fontSize of the input text from your TextInput:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 email:     {
    fontSize:   12, <-- Textsize of Input-Text and Placeholder-Text
 },
})
```

Maybe your solution works without px?! But i don´t think so. If you want to have a different PlaceholderText than the InputText, than you could maybe acces the onChangeText-Method of TextInput and change the fontSize as soon as you type something into the Textfield.

Comment: This is correct answer. You can modify text size of placeholder by changing the fontSize through Stylesheet object. But there's no such property as `placeholderTextSize`. It only works for the color.

Answer (score 7):

TextInput component can be created like this.

```js
    <TextInput
    value={value}
    style={value ? styles.input : styles.placeholder}
    placeholderTextColor="white"
    {...props}
   />
```

`Note: You can't directly change the size of placeholder's text`

The above solution works because the size you give to normal textInput will directly apply to placeholder

Trick here is that we are conditionally checking if user typed something

On typing value will be true and hence we will apply input style otherwise placeholder style notice style is applied to textInput instead of placeholder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way (as far as I remember) to directly change the font size of only the placeholder, since when you change the fontSize using styles, you're changing both, the input fontSize as well as placeholder fontSize. However, there is a way tho...

```
const [ text, setText ] = useState<string>('');
```

and then use the state to check whether the input field is empty or not. If it is empty, then change the fontSize as:

```
{ fontSize: text ? 18 : 12 }
```

However, it is important to note that even tho this method works, but the delay caused by the re-render is, of course, noticable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextInput 
style={{fontSize:12}} 
placeholder='any text' 
onChangeText={(input)=>this.setState({input: input})}
placeholderTextColor='green'/>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: when you increase the fontSize the placeholder size increased

Answer (score 0):

Just need to increase the 'fontSize' property of TextInput. Then the placeholder size will automatically get increase

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31859398)

Answer (score 0):

here is your code

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.email}
    value={this.state.email} 
    placeholder="Email"
    placeholderTextColor="red"
    //placeholderTextSize = 20px <-------it's not working
    onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}
    onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}/>
```

here is your style

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    email: {
        borderColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 10,
        height: 55,
        width: 378,
        marginLeft: 8.27,
        marginTop: 5,
        fontSize:15,  <------------add this line it's working 
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The font size of the placeholder is same as the font size of text field. This means you could specify the placeholder font size inside the style prop as normal.

```js
<TextField placeholder="email" style={{ fontSize: 20 }} />
```

If you need to customise the font size of the placeholder and value differently. You could use is check if there is a input value exists and apply style accordingly.